# Divergence theorem application

Tags: integration

Let $F(x,y,z)= (x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})(xi+yj+zk)$ and let S be a sphere of radius a about the origin.

Compute $\iint_{S} F \cdot n d S$

Directly and by using the divergence theorem. There should be a dot product symbol between those 2 above.

The divergence formula states $\iint_{S} F \cdot  n d S = \iiint_{V}divFdv$
and so $\iiint_{V}divFdv=\iiint_{V}(2x+2y+2z)dxdydz$.
I don't understand what this says let alone how to compute it. I can't understand the notation used or what they are even asking me to find please help!

Comment: $ \iiint_V $ denotes the integral over the volume. Since you are integrating over the sphere, you can try to change to spherical coordinates.

Comment: You can check out this link to see how it is done: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) .

Comment: Please check that my math formatting and minor fixes are OK.